# PIXI.Graphics vertices resolution

Tags: javascript, performance, pixi.js

When using the PIXI.Graphics class to draw shapes, I discovered a huge performance boost by drawing my shapes a fraction of the wanted size and scaled it back to fullscreen, because of the reduction of the number of vertices used to draw the shape.

I wonder if there is a more direct way to tell PIXI to draw shapes with a reduced resolution/with less vertices? I could not find anything in the docs.

Any idea to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: This seems like question about internal mechanics of Pixi.js  . I suggest to ask it also at https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I just add it too. I will update here if I find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question has been answered in the [github discussion's tab](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/8373).

To quote [@bigtimebuddy](https://github.com/bigtimebuddy) there :

> You may want to checkout [GRAPHICS_CURVES](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.html#GRAPHICS_CURVES) options. You can try increasing the `maxSegments` and `maxLength`.